# How to create this sequence in ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

When we 
input : 10

output :01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10

When we 
input :103

output :001 002 003...010 011 012 013.....100 101 002 103

How to create this sequence in ruby or python ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I tried making an algo by taking count of the input  , if its 2 digit , then append  one 0 till its count (inputs count ) reaches 2, if its 3 digit then append 2 zeroes till its count reaches 2, then 1 zero and when count become 3, then no zero will appened, But i dont know how to implement it

Comment: How is the sequence formed? I don't understand the logic for your second sequence at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby implementation:

```
n = gets
p (1..n.to_i).map{ |i| i.to_s.rjust(n.to_s.length, "0") }.join(" ")
```

Here `rjust` will add leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Another one in Ruby:

```
n = gets.chomp
'1'.rjust(n.size, '0').upto(n) { |s| puts s }
```

[`String#upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-upto) handles numeric strings in a special way:

```
'01'.upto('10').to_a
#=> ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10"]
```

Answer (score 1):

A very basic Python implementation. Note that it's a generator so it returns one value at a time.

```
def get_range(n):
    len_n = len(str(n))
    for num in range(1, n + 1):
        output = str(num)
        while len(output) < len_n:
            output = '0' + output
        yield output

for i in get_range(100):
    print(i)

>> 001
   002
   ...
   ...
   009
   010
   011
   ..
   ..
   099
   100
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `zfill` you can add leading zeroes.

```
num=input()
for i in range(1,int(num)+1):
    print (str(i).zfill(len(num)))
```

Comment: Nice, short and Pythonic solution.